# jquery not working with wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Script is actually quite simple:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    setTimeout( function()
    {
        jQuery('.menu-header').fadeOut();
    }, 2000);
});
```

And should show menu after everything is loaded... And it works! But not with wordpress..  Also I know, that we should use jQuery insted of $.
In my functions.php I add jquery:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', 'load_jquery' );
function load_jquery() 
{
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
```

But this script is not working at all...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Type `alert(jQuery.fn.jquery)` and tell us what that outputs.

Comment: check jQuery scrpit files may be repeating , try calling that function without this code --- "add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', 'load_jquery' );
function load_jquery() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}"

Comment: Your result source page has jquery scripts inside?

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum - I get nothing, no even empty alertbox

Comment: @Abhishek deleted this code and still nothing

Comment: then check the jQuery file path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this reads easier...

```
     <?php
     function custom_load_jquery() {
     ?>
     <script type="text/javascript">
          jQuery(document).ready(function(){
               setTimeout(function(){
                    jQuery('.menu-header').fadeOut(2000);
               }
          });
     </script>
     <?php
     }

     add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', 'custom_load_jquery' );
     ?>
```

and wp_enqueue_script should be the correct place to load up the jQuery code... I'm not totally sure "load_jquery" isn't already in use, better to customize it.  Also, do you have the fadeOut function correct? Check my recent edit...

Comment: What? Dude, you just combined JavaScript and PHP into the same codeblock. Derp'd.

Comment: oops. echo that.. I will fix...  Apologies. Thanx, Nick.

Comment: @zipzit - quite cool code! But in this case not resolving my problem. Menu still loading as previous.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is not running in no Conflict mode.

> The jQuery library included with WordPress is set to the noConflict()
>   mode (see wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js). This is to prevent
>   compatibility problems with other JavaScript libraries that WordPress
>   can link.
>
> In the noConflict() mode, the global $ shortcut for jQuery is not
>   available.

Solution :

```
var $j = jQuery;

$j(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout(function(){
    $j('.menu-header').fadeOut();}, 2000);
});
```

Working jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/dy5Mu/

Comment: I`ve tryed it, and still nothing

Comment: demo added. check it.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone will have a similar problem as mine, there is solution. All others said true. Thing is jQuery has been add later, then I call script. So... add code to the footer.php and it will be fine :D

Without any modifications at header or functions, just add to footer.php this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
    jQuery('.menu-header').fadeIn();}, 3000);
});
```

However, I would like to say thank you all who tryied to help me. This forum is the best, and all of you are amazing!

## **Thank you!**